# retrieve image data from mongodb and show on browser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

```
{ _id: 5a97c9a9b5a49f188c222399,
    size: 44706,
    image:
     Binary {
       _bsontype: 'Binary',
       sub_type: 0,
       position: 44706,
       buffer: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 06 40 00 00 03 b4 08 02 00 00 00 72 55 6d 58 00 00 ae 69 49 44 41 54
78 da ec dd 07 78 56 e5 dd ... > },
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    image_name: 'nodejs-frameworks.png' }
```

This is my Data in the image collection. I am finding difficult to covert this data into an image. I tried by converting image data into base64 data but didn't work. here is my code.

```
getImage: function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id;
    db.image.getImage(id, function (item) {
        console.log(item);
        res.contentType(item[0].mimetype);

        res.send(item[0].image.buffer.toString('base64'));
    });
}
```

The getImage function calls getImage function in another file which retrieves the above JSON data.  I have searched and gone through different solutions but unable to understand them. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain this properly, but below code worked. One reason that I can think of is may res.send is not sending proper header type, that's why res.write worked(I am not sure, just an assumption).

```
getImage: function (req, res) {
        let id = req.params.id;
        db.image.getImage(id, function (item) {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': item[0].mimetype
            });
            res.write(item[0].image.buffer);
            res.end();
        });
    }
```